# How and when to use IMEX runge-kutta

Tags: runge-kutta

i have come across method of IMEX Runge-Kutta written by Kennedy and Carpenter in july 2001. The method consist of two kind that is "implicit and explicit"

can i use the ERK@explicit part only to solve the intial value problem, as if i treat the method as another embedded Runge-Kutta?
is it against the algorithm/rule of the method?

Comment: Are you talking about the algorithm described in this report (for example)? https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20010075154.pdf
If yes, at least a link inside your question would be very useful.